# Mvvmcross unittest for InvokeOnMainThread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have in my init of the viewmodel the follow code:

```
public void Init(int id)
{
   Task.Run(() => {
        var loadedObjects = service.GetAllById(id);
        InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
           foreach(var objectA in loadedObjects)
           {
              Items.Add(objectA);
           }
        });
   }
}
```

My tests is like this:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldTest()
{
   //For additional Setup of MvvmCross and registering of Dispatcher
   Setup();

   var viewModel = new ViewModelObjects();
   viewModel.Init(1);

   Assert.AreEqual(1, viewModel.Items.Count);
}
```

When I run my test the assert is running first after that the InvokeOnMainThread is called.
My unit has a dispatcher (From: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Testing)

1. Reason for Task.Run is rest of GUI needs to be rendered.
2. InvokeOnMainThread triggers the ProperyChanged
3. Tries like (http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20140324-HandlingPropertyChangedEventInMvvmCrossViewModelUnitTests.html) didnt work

Any idea how i can test the Items?

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run` without an await just continues execution of the code. So what you see in your `Items` collection, might not be what you expect as the code inside of the expression body in the `Task.Run` probably hasn't finished executing.

This is not really a MvvmCross issue. However a general threading issue.

I suggest that you use `InitAsync` instead, and await the method. Your tests can be async too.

Comment: You are right, however it will "lock" the app before rendering the rest while waiting the request

Comment: No, it wouldn't `lock` the application, as it's `async`